# AspNet MVC 5 too slow - iddle time between pipeline methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, glimpse

I'm using Glimpse to debug some perfomance problems in my website, and it seems that the server/framework sits iddle for too long between method calls.

1. This [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53Tl-6S_RiiSkhQYlFFdW5Kb0k/view?usp=sharing) shows 320 ms of server time;
2. This [second picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53Tl-6S_RiiSlo3U3VGX1ZvTFU/view?usp=sharing) reveals that 125.29 ms are used by ViewResult.ExecuteResult (I understand that as "rendering", which seems pretty slow to me, considering that my views are pre-compiled - more on that below);
3. But the really odd thing here is that more than 100 ms are pretty much wasted with iddle time, as you can verify in [this picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B53Tl-6S_RiiYWp0U0E0dzFQTXM).

Those little blocks representing server work sometimes account for 0 ms! But then there's a lapse of about 15 ms before the next block.

Is it really iddle time? Do you have any tips for where to look next, or how to optimize this?

---

**Disclaimer**: I've been looking into this for a week or so, and I have already found and applied those general performance recommendations, like:

- Only one View Engine is active (RazorViewEngine);
- Run in Release mode;
- Specify full view paths, like "~/Views/Folder/ActionName.cshtml".

Besides that, Donut Caching is active, views are pre-compiled with Razor Generator, and I'm using Glimpse for diagnostics. Anyways, I've tried disabling these things to ensure that they were not the offenders, and I verified that they're actually improving the times.

Thanks in advance.